# Torrents cause all other ethernet and wifi to drop out completely

Tags: networking, router, internet, bittorrent, qbittorrent

Ive just switched ISP and now whenever I use torrents only the machine downloading  gets internet.

All other ethernet connections drop out as if they've been disconnected and the wifi network disappears completey, it's not even listed in available networks to connect to.

Ive got to limit qbittorent to no more than 100**k**bps up and down, and Im on a 500**m**bps connection.

Ive tried other types of downloads and everything stays up (I downloaded a 100gb game with no issues - I never d/l that much via torrent). Ive also tried several different machines with the same outcome (network drops out for others).
I would expect if my ISP was throttling because of torrents that the machine downloading would be slowed, but its not. Its like that machine steals all the bandwidth from my network regardless of how much it actually needs.

My old ISP was 100mbps and I had no issues.
I have no separate router just the ISP one they provide. Ive had a technician come round and tell me the router is fine and the connections are all set up correctly. I do use several gigabit switches to connect all ethernet devices.

Does anyone know what might be causing the issue and hiw it can be solved?

Comment: How many simultaneous connections do you allow?

Comment: If you can enter the login page of the router, check if it has any limits defined that could explain this, for example QoS (Quality of Service)?

Comment: On qbit ive set it to max 100 connections. The ISP router has no QoS functions. Im considering getting a separate router to solve that but only if I cant figure this issue out without one

Comment: What happens if you set qbit to 2 connections ?

Comment: So I set it to 2 and reset the speed limits to infinite. it seems like the connections are stable and Im getting up to around 500kbps download

Comment: Ive not even had it 3 weeks

Comment: I added a few newer torrents and even with just 2 connections the network fall apart

Comment: set torrent client download bandwidth to half your internet speed.

Comment: My internet is 500mbps. It all drops out if the speed goes over 100kbps

Comment: I reset the router and after a few initial connection issues Im now able to set d/l speed to 10mbps. Which I guess is fast enough, but Im still confused as to what the issue is

Comment: Just as an update. The connection was gradually going back to the worse case, so I've just ended up getting a router with QoS and putting the ISP hub into modem mode. Everyting seems to be running optimally now